# Iterating through collection items and checking each property for a valid value

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

I have a collection of objects (IQueryable). Each object has various properties, some string some datetime, I'm not concerned about the datetime properties. How can I iterate through each object and return a collection of those objects that maybe have null values in one or more fields

For simplicity, consider a collection of Employees

Each employee may have two properties:
FirstName (string)
LastName (string)

I'd like to have a method that could iterate through all employees in the employee collection and return a collection of employees that either have first name or last name missing, i.e null or an empty string.

using .NET 3.5 with C#

Comment: You should be more specific, using reflection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Employees.Where(e => string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FirstName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.LastName))
```

Comment: "For simplicity...." This works in a very specific case and gives no indication how to get started on approaching the more general problem.

Comment: @Jason, I would strongly prefer writing the validation checks statically in code over a more generic approach that specifies the conditions in some other form.  Either way you're encoding the checks in some way and writing it as straightforward code in a well-defined business layer is more maintainable than a more round-about architecture.

Comment: @Dan Bryant: Disagree. Specifications are reusable, embedded validation checks are not. Decoupling the validation checks from the validation mechanism is more, not less, maintainable than what you propose.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you started:

```
var properties = typeof(Employee).GetProperties()
                                 .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
foreach(var employee in employees) {
    foreach(var property in properties) {
         string value = (string)property.GetValue(employee, null);
         if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) {
             yield return employee;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

It's clear how to generalize this using generics.

Even better is to just have a concrete class that implements some interface `ISpecification<T>` (obvious interface method is `bool IsSatisfiedBy(T entity)`) and then

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetInvalidEntities<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source,
    ISpecification<T> specification
) {
    return source.Where(x => !specification.IsSatisfiedBy(x));
}
```

For example:

```
public class EmployeeSpecification : ISpecification<Employee> {
    public bool IsSatisfiedBy(Employee entity) {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(entity != null);
        return !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.FirstName) &&
               !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entity.LastName);
    }
}
```

Then you can say:

```
// IEnumerable<Employee> employees;
// EmployeeSpecification specification;
var invalidEmployees = employees.GetInvalidEntitites(specification);
```

Comment: I think the question is about only two properties (FirstName and LastName) and should cater for empty strings

Comment: @Jakub Konecki: No, `Employee` is just an example. I think he's looking for something more general.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then reflection is a good way - You might want to extend your first code sample with the check for property type (string) and empty strings as values

Comment: or Func<T, bool> instead of ISpecification<T>

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a second collection "invalidEmployees"

Iterate through Employee collection.  Check current Employee for null values (or any other characteristic) then add them to the "invalidEmployees" collection.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question, the solution should be pretty trivial:

```
  IEnumerable<Employee> collection = iQuaryable.AsEnumerable();
  List<Employee> myCollection = new List<Employee>();

  foreach(var emp in collection) 
  {
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp.LastName) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(emp.FirstName))
             myCollection.Add(emp);
  }
```

where the iQuaryable is the instance of your IQuaryable implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to explicitly state which fields for which your method will check the objects?
Or do you want all string properties checked?
Or are the properties static and known at compile time?
Are the objects all the same type?

It could be as simple as a where clause like shown in other answers:

```
var nullPropItems = objectCollection.Where(ob => string.IsNullOrEmpty(ob.Property));
```

Or it could be as complex as specifying the string property names you want to check and iterating them:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> HasNullStringProperties<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, params string[] propertyNames)
{
    var properties = items.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperties();

    foreach(var item in items)
        foreach(string propertyName in propertyNames)
        {
            var propertyInfo = properties.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Name.Equals(propertyName));
            if (null != propertyInfo)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyInfo.GetValue(item, null) as string))
                    yield return item;
            }
        }
}
```

Callable with something like:

```
var items = objectCollection.HasNullStringProperties("FirstName", "LastName", "OrganizationName");
```

You could further cut down on the number of properties you check against if you pre-filter for string types. After the GetProperties() add

```
.Where(prop => prop.GetType() == typeof(string));
```